# Python2 merge list of lists by value

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 4 elements and it looks like:

```
L = [['grape','green',2, 100], ['grape','purple',3,3], ['apple','red',2, 15], ['apple','greed',3, 10],
     ['apple','red',4, 4], ['banana','yellow',2, 3]]
```

I would like to have a function to merge that list by the first element, concatenate the second and third element, then sum up the last element to get the output like:

```
[['grape',['green,purple'],[2,3],103],['banana','yellow',2, 3],['apple',['red','green','red'],[2,3,4],29]
```

I tried the follow code:

```
[(x,sum(map(itemgetter(3),y))) for x,y in itertools.groupby(L, itemgetter(0))], which can successfully sum up the last element, but

[(x,(map(itemgetter(1),y)),(map(itemgetter(2),y)),sum(map(itemgetter(3),y))) for x,y in itertools.groupby(L, itemgetter(0))]
```

did not work as I expected.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If there's only one item in the group should the second and third element in the result be lists?

Comment: Either list or unlist (elements) will be fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby()` you need two separate iteration:

```
In [20]: [[i[0], j, k, sum(z)] for i, j, k, z in [zip(*g) for _, g in groupby(L, itemgetter(0))]]
Out[20]: 
[['grape', ('green', 'purple'), (2, 3), 103],
 ['apple', ('red', 'greed', 'red'), (2, 3, 4), 29],
 ['banana', ('yellow',), (2,), 3]]
```

Here is another way using `collections.defaultdict`, but not that optimize :

```
In [34]: d = defaultdict(list)

In [35]: for i, j, k, z in L:
            d[i].append((j, k, z))
   ....:     

In [36]: [[i, j, k, sum(z)] for i, j, k, z in [[i, *zip(*values)] for i, values in d.items()]]
Out[36]: 
[['banana', ('yellow',), (2,), 3],
 ['apple', ('red', 'greed', 'red'), (2, 3, 4), 29],
 ['grape', ('green', 'purple'), (2, 3), 103]]
```

*Note* that `*zip(...)` within a list is called in-place unpacking and is only available in python 3.5+.

Comment: Note that result here is `['banana', ('yellow',), (2,), 3]` instead of `['banana','yellow',2, 3]` as in the question.

Comment: @niemmi Yep, but let's leave that as a task for OP ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution based on `groupby`, a bit less entangled and giving exactly the requested output:

```
import operator, itertools

l = [['grape','green',2, 100], ['grape','purple',3,3], ['apple','red',2, 15], ['apple','greed',3, 10],
     ['apple','red',4, 4], ['banana','yellow',2, 3]]


res = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(l, operator.itemgetter(0)):
    i,j,k,l = [i[0] if len(i) == 1 else list(i) for i in zip(*group)]
    res.append([key, j, k, l if type(l) == int else sum(l)])

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[['grape', ['green', 'purple'], [2, 3], 103], ['apple', ['red', 'greed', 'red'], [2, 3, 4], 29], ['banana', 'yellow', 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks! A safe way to do it!